# matching a number pattern between special characters

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to extract only the number 120068018

```
!false!|!!|!!|!!|!!|!120068018!|!!|!false!
```

I am rather new to regular expressions and am finding this a daunting task.

I have tried using the pattern as the numbers always start with 1200

```
'/^1200+!\$/'
```

but that does not seem to work.

Comment: What programming language? You'll at least need some capturing parentheses: `'/^(1200+!)\$/'` but why are you using `^` and `$` anchors?

Comment: Highly recommend www.regex101.com as a sandbox (and that explains what works, and why).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your number always starts with `1200`, you can do

```
/1200\d*/
```

This matches a string that starts with `1200` plus "however many digits follow". Depending on the 'dialect' of regex that you use, you might find

```
/1200[0-9]*/
```

more robust; or

```
/1200[[:digit:]]*/
```

which is more "readable"

Any of these can be "captured" with parentheses. Again, depending on the dialect, you may or may not need to escape these (add `\` in front). Example

```
echo '||!!||!!||!!120012345||##!!@@!!||' | sed 's/^.*\(1200[0-9]*\).*$/\1/'
```

produces

```
120012345
```

just as you wanted. Explanation:

```
sed              stream editor command
s                substitute
^.*              everything from start of string until
\(               start capture group
1200             the number 1200
[0-9]*           followed by any number of digits
\)               end capture
.*$              everything from here to end of line
/\1/             and replace with the contents of the first capture group
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the regular expression you need:

```
/[0-9]+/
```

**[0-9]** Matches any number from 0 to 9

The **+** sign means *1 or more times*.

If you want to get any number starting with 1200, then it would be

```
/1200[0-9]*/
```

Here I am using ***** because it allows *zero or more*. Otherwise, the number 1200 wouldn't be captured.

If you want to **capture** (extract) the String, surround it with parenthesis:

```
/(1200[0-9]*)/
```

Comment: I assume you're trying to get **any** number in the String. If it's specific for the number you mentioned, it'd be /120068018/ but it wouldn't make much sense, I guess.

Comment: the numbers I am looking for always starts with 1200

Comment: just edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
/1200\d+/
```

\d is a meta-character that will match any digits.

Your regular expression didn't work because:

1. ^ matches start of a string. You didn't have your number there.
2. $ matches end of the string. Again, your number is in the middle of the string.
3. - applies to the immediately preceding character, meta-character or group. So 1200+ means 120 followed by 1 or more zeroes.